# read line from console as input for 2D array in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, multidimensional-array, readline

Trying to read lines of integer from console separated by a single character space into a 2D array. I have tried using `split(separator:maxSplits:omittingEmptySubsequences:)`, but it cannot be cast into an integer.

The 2D array that has to be read from console as input looks like this

```
1 1 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 2 4 4 0
0 0 0 2 0 0
0 0 1 2 4 0
```

This is the code I tried

```
var arr = [[Int]]()
for i in 0 ... 5 {
    var a = readLine()?.components(separatedBy: " ")
   var arr[i] = [a?.split(separator: " ", maxSplits: 1, omittingEmptySubsequences: false)] as? Int

}
```

And the error is

```
cast from '[ArraySlice]?' to unrelated type 'Int' always fails
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in 0...5 {    
  var aux = [Int]()

  readLine()?.split(separator: " ").map({
    aux.append(Int($0)!)
  })
  arr.append(aux)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this one

```
for i in 0...5 {
    arr += readLine()!.components(separatedBy: " ").map{ Int($0)! }
}
```